# How to disable the scrolling buttons in GridView?

Tags: java, android

I have display the number of buttons in GridView, in mobile if touch on button and scroll it, the buttons are moving, i want to disable the scrolling of buttons. but in emulator it is not scrolling.

Please give any idea....

Please help some one to disable the buttons scrolling in Gridview.....

Answer (score 0):

Use the setOnTouchListener for GridView the scrolling has disabled.

gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

```
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
```